# Calling function defined inside powershell script

Tags: powershell

Not sure if I'm doing this right, as it's only the 3rd powershell script I've ever written, so apologize for such a basic question.

I have a loop that needs to be run in two to three different areas. Rather than repeat the code over and over, I'd like to place it in a defined function and call from inside the script.

The function uses a simple `switch` statement to get the description of a local group, then returns the `string` variable holding the description.

The function seems to process fine, however after the return statement I get the following error message

> Exception setting "description": "The following exception occurred while retrieving member "description": "The group name could not be found.

This is a pretty basic feature of Powershell, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Below is the complete script. The code in the `try` block calls the function `createGroupAndUsers`, which in turn calls the function `addDescription`, which is where the error is occurring.

```powershell
#HERE IS THE FUNCTION THROWING THE ERROR
Function addDescription($groupName)
{
    switch($groupName)
    {
        "WebDevelopers"        {$description = "Developers for this Web Server.  They have RDP rights and update rights to the webcontent share." }
        "AgentPaymentUpdater"  {$description = "Used by OKeeffe WCF Web Service to update DSS"}
        "AgencyCloneRequestor" {$description = "Used by OKeeffe WCF Web Service to clone agent data from DSS"}
        "WynsureServiceInquiry"{$description = "Used by AgentInformationService WCF Web Service to query DSS"}
        "BundleInquiry"        {$description = "Used by AgentInformationService WCF Web Service to query DSS"}
        "BundleUpdate"         {$description = "Used by AgentInformationService WCF Web Service to query DSS"}
        "DistributorInquiry"   {$description = "Used by AgentInformationService WCF Web Service to query DSS"}
    }   

    #return statement throws exception
    return $description
}

#ABOVE FUNCTION CALLED BY THIS ONE
Function createGroupAndUsers($groupName, $computerName)
{ 
    #clear variables from previous run
    if($objGroup)
    {
        Clear-Variable $objGroup
    }
    if($Members)
    {
        Clear-Variable $Members
    }
    if($MemberName)
    {
        Clear-Variable $MemberName
    }
    if($tempArray)
    {
        Clear-Variable $tempArray
    }

    #create group and add description
    $objGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/$groupName"

    if(-not $objGroup)
    {
        Write-Host "Creating Local Group $groupName" -ForegroundColor green
        $objGroup = $cn.Create("Group", $groupName)
        $objGroup.setinfo()
    }

    Write-Host "Setting Description for Local Group $groupName" -ForegroundColor green
    $objGroup.description = addDescription $groupName
    $objGroup.setinfo()

    #pull group members from remote machine
    $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Server $computerName
    $Members | ForEach-Object {$MemberNames += $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) + ",";}

    $tempArray = $MemberNames -split ","
    foreach($member in $tempArray)
    {
        Write-Host "Adding $member as user for Local Group $groupName" -ForegroundColor green
        $objGroup.Add("WinNT://DOMAIN/$member, user")
    }
}

#'MAIN' BLOCK OF CODE THAT CALLS ABOVE FUNCTIONS
try{
         #Periscope and OKeeffe
         $computerName = "DEVWB37" 
         $groupArray = @("WebDevelopers", "AgentPaymentUpdater", "AgencyCloneRequestor")

          foreach($groupName in $groupArray)
          {
            createGroupAndUsers $groupName $computerName
          }
 }

catch{
     write-host "Caught an exception:" -ForegroundColor Red
     write-host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" -ForegroundColor Red
     write-host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Looks like a scope issue. What if you initialise it before the switch?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the function?

Comment: Added the full script to the post. The `try` block calls the function `createGroupAndUsers` which in turn calls the `addDescription` function.. which is where the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to the way that you're calling it:

```powershell
 $objGroup.description = addDescription $groupName
```

Try instead to first call the function separately with the same input, and see what the output is.

Then try to set `$objGroup.description` to a static string value and see what the result is.

Between those two you should get more information or an answer to what's going wrong.

Comment: The problem was the `$objGroup` is somehow null, so there was no `description` property to set. Error was hiding in plain sight :)